# Package tm: How do I avoid removing stopwords

Tags: r, tm, stop-words

I want to avoid removing stopwords but I find that regardless of the parameter setting of `tm` it always removes some stopwords.

```
library(tm)
documents <- c("This is a list containing the tallest buildings in San    Francisco")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(documents))
matrix <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,control=list(stopwords=FALSE))
colnames(matrix)
# [1] "buildings"  "containing" "francisco"  "list"       "san"       
# [6] "tallest"    "the"        "this"
```

`DocumentTermMatrix` seems to remove stopwords "is" and "in".

How can I avoid this? Setting `stopwords=TRUE` only prevents removal of "the".
How can I prevent also removal of "is" and "in"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not that `DocumentTermMatrix` treats "is" and "in" as stopwords, but because they are words shorter than 3 characters. The default for the tokenizer is to treat strings of length 3 to infinity as words, i.e. exclude others shorter than 3.

You can modify your control as below to include words which are single letter onwards

```
matrix <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,control=list(stopwords=FALSE,
                                                 wordLengths=c(1, Inf)))
```

And I believe this is what you want

```
> colnames(matrix)
 [1] "a"          "buildings"  "containing" "francisco"  "in"         "is"        
 [7] "list"       "san"        "tallest"    "the"        "this"
```

You didn't mention "a" in your question, so if you want to exclude that (and others like "I"), set the `wordLength` to start from 2.